# jupyter dashboard server is still supported?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to make a demo of an interactive dashboard in jupyter notebook to share with others. I was wondering is the jupyter dashboard server still supported or not? As I realized, all the github repositories related to these projects are at least back to 1 year ago.

Is there any other solution to have an interactive web apps dashboard like R/Shiny but supports other languages too?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the point of writing this, the question is three years old so I might be a late answering. However, for the sake of anyone else who might be searching for an answer..

To the first part of the question: By now jupyter_dashboards appears to have been put to rest. It can now be found in the [jupyter-attic](https://github.com/jupyter-attic/dashboards/blob/master/docs/source/index.rst) which is described as a place for "[o]ld repos from Project Jupyter that are in "cold storage", with no further development or maintenance. Purely for archival/historical purposes."

To the second part: Look like [Viola](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) might be a good alternative. As for languages, since it is Jupyter notebook widget ("addon", if I may use the term), it appears as if you could use any language for which there is a [Jupyter kernel](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) (i).

> (i) *I doubt I'll ever find the need to test this statement so happy adventuring!*